# How do I show the beach ball in windows mobile using C#?

Tags: user-interface, windows-mobile, notifications

How do I show the beach ball in windows mobile using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the wait cursor?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.usewaitcursor(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.waitcursor.aspx

Comment: It helps to know what to call it. I just see the old spinning beach ball from Mac 7.5.